# How to remove tuples nested on a list?

Tags: python, list, nested, tuples

```
in_tup = [('hello', 'hi', 'bye'), ('hello', 'yes', 'no'), ('alright', 'yes', 'okay')]
```

The goal is to remove the other tuples. The code will allow the user to accept the first 2 indexes which it will remove the whole tuple. This is my code so far:

```
first = input()
second = input()

out_tup = [i for i in in_tup if i[0] == first]
out_tup1 = [i for i in out_tup if i[1] == second]

for i in out_tup1:
    a = ("{}, {}, {} has been removed".format(i[0],i[1],i[2]))
    print(a)

    a = [i for i in in_tup if in_tup != out_tup1]
    print(a)
```

But when I input, for example "hello" and "hi" it still prints everything:

```
[('hello', 'hi', 'bye'), ('hello', 'yes', 'no'), ('alright', 'yes', 'okay')]
```

I want the output to only have these:

```
[('hello', 'yes', 'no'), ('alright', 'yes', 'okay')]
```

Comment: in_tup is obviously != out_tup1 as long as you remove something.I think you want to check a = [i for i in in_tup if i  not in out_tup1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that the condition `in_tup != out_tup1` is True since you're comparing two lists of different length when the inputs are "hello" and "hi".

I believe that what you are trying to do is check whether the elements of in_tup are in out_tup1, so try the following:

```
a = [i for i in in_tup if i not in out_tup1]
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the condition `a = [i for i in in_tup if i not in out_tup1]` is always True, so you end up printing everything in the list. I have solved the problem, cleaned up the code a little bit, and replaced the format string with a more modern f-string.

```py
in_tup = [('hello', 'hi', 'bye'), ('hello', 'yes', 'no'), ('alright', 'yes', 'okay')]

first = input()
second = input()

out_tup = [i for i in in_tup if i[0] == first]
out_tup1 = [i for i in out_tup if i[1] == second]

for i in out_tup1:
    print(f"{i[0]}, {i[1]}, {i[2]} has been removed")
    print([i for i in in_tup if i not in out_tup1])
```

Note that your code can be further simplified as follows:

```py
in_tup = [('hello', 'hi', 'bye'), ('hello', 'yes', 'no'), ('alright', 'yes', 'okay')]

first = input()
second = input()

for tup in in_tup:
    if tup[0] == first and tup[1] == second:
        out_tup = tup

print(f"{out_tup[0]}, {out_tup[1]}, {out_tup[2]} has been removed")
print([i for i in in_tup if i != out_tup])
```